# Getting Color from AttributeSet

Tags: java, android, xml, colors

i'm trying to get a color, set in my AttributeSet, which references a color, defined in my colors.xml.

Here's what the **colors.xml** looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    ...
    <color name="colorBlack">#000000</color>
</resources>
```

The **attrs.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
     <declare-styleable name="TestView">
          ...
          <attr name="lineColor" format="color" value="@color/colorBlack" />
     </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

And the **TestView.java**

```
int mLineColor;

public TestView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.TestView, 0, 0);
    try {
        ...
        mLineColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.TestView_lineColor,  0);
    } finally {
        a.recycle();
    }
}
```

For some reason, getting the attribute **lineColor** via

```
a.getColor(R.styleable.TestView_lineColor,  0);
```

will always return the default value of 0.

Which means, i cannot go ahead and set the color into a Paint object, to color my shapes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/13512850/4519859

Comment: In my case, the color attribute is set fixed in the AttributeSet (value="@color/colorBlack") and is not a variable which is set when the object is being created.

Comment: Is TestView your class? and where are you using this ?

Comment: While i'm typing this... is this even possible? To set a constant in the styleables?

Comment: Yea, TestView is my class in this example, i'm setting it up in my activity via the xml-layout.

Answer (score 0):

Though it is very late. Let me share the solution that worked for me.

Somehow a.getColor is always returning 0. Thus, I use a.getDrawable(). This works very well for me for setting background color to a view.

To get Color you can use

```
(ColorDrawable) a.getDrawable()).getColor();
```

Also I define format="reference". this works fine even for hex color code.

```
<attr name="lineColor" format="reference" />
```