# How to set TextColor from Custom style attribute(R.attr.text_color) Android

Tags: android

I am changing the app theme with a switch toggle. Then all the XML contents work perfectly. But I need a color in my java code.

I tried :

```
getResources.getColor(R.attr.text_color);
```

but it is not working.

Thank you.

Comment: try using getResources.getColor(R.color.text_color);

Comment: I'm using different themes and that is dynamic, That's why I am using R.attr.text_color.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13512850/how-can-i-reliably-get-a-color-from-an-attributeset/13513272) help, or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17700862/custom-attr-get-color-returns-invalid-values)?

Comment: Actually, I want to change my Tabs color inside tab layout programmatically.

Comment: I Changed that in XML using "?attr/tabcolor". Now I need that color in my MainActivity.class file please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use attributes to change text color from activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27016464/how-to-use-attributes-to-change-text-color-from-activity)